# Visual confirmation of keyboard layout change in OS X Yosemite

Tags: macos, keyboard

I might be mistaken, but I seem to remember there once was a visual confirmation when changing the keyboard layout in older versions of OS X. It was some kind of small grey window in the middle of the screen showing all currently available layouts (and highlighting the active one) for a few seconds after each change.

Is there a way to re-enable this in Yosemite? I am *not* talking about the flag symbol for the menu bar which can be switched on and off in system preferences. I prefer a very clean menu bar with as little as possible icons. I have set a keyboard shortcut for switching the layout (which is working), but I get no confirmation or information about the current layout.

Comment: If you like a clean menu bar, try [Bartender](http://www.macbartender.com/). It lets you hide icons while letting them be accessible. Also, you can tell it to temporarily show an icon when it changes, which could be a good solution to your question here. The flag could be hidden except for the five seconds after you switch layouts, for instance.

Comment: @timothymh Good suggestion. I know Bartender, but forgot that it can display and auto hide symbols after a change. It would be an acceptable work around.

Answer (score 1):

It's still there, but it only shows when <kbd>⌥</kbd> is held for a slightly longer time. A quick <kbd>⌥</kbd> + <kbd>⇥</kbd> will not trigger this window.

Comment: Unfortunately holding the option key for a longer time does not work for me so far.

Comment: Hmm that is strange, try holding the option key for a second, tapping tab, whilst continuing to hold option for another second.

Comment: No success so far...and I have a newly installed system, just a few days old. Does this also work with other shortcuts? I can't seem to set it to option + end (I instead use option + pageDown).

Comment: I don't know, I keep mine with the default shortcut