# Flash current keyboard layout on screen when changed

Tags: keyboard

I am currently running MacOS Ventura 13.3.1 and I often switch between three different keyboard layouts. I prefer to have the menu bar hidden so as not to clutter the workspace, which means I don't see which keyboard layout is active.

On some previous versions of MacOS, when you changed the keyboard layout with a shortcut, a transparent gray window with a list of the available layouts was briefly displayed with the current one highlighted. It is my understanding that this feature has now been removed (see this question, [Visual confirmation of keyboard layout change in OS X Yosemite](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/186678/visual-confirmation-of-keyboard-layout-change-in-os-x-yosemite)).

Is there a third party way to replicate this behavior in newer versions of MacOS, or some other way to get the same functionality?

Comment: This alternative keyboard switcher might be helpful:  https://github.com/hatashiro/kawa

Answer (score 1):

Works in Ventura 13.3.1.

To display switching input sources on screen ("transparent gray window with a list of the available layouts") use keyboard shortcut set in:

System Settings > Keyboard > Keyboard Shortcuts > Input Sources > Select the previous input source

By default it should be Control - Space.

In order to actually see grey window one should keep Control pressed and use space to switch between input sources.

Comment: That is the version I am running (I have corrected the version number in the question), and while this shortcut switches the intput source, it does not, for me, display source in the middle of the screen.

Comment: Is it so when you keep Control pressed and use space to switch between input sources?

Comment: That does work! Thank you! I had it mapped to F2, and prissing that did not show the window. Seems the gray box with the different inputs only shows up if you use the default mapping. If you write this as an aswer I'll accept it.